# Motivation and application for stochastic geometry.

Tags: geometry, stochastic-processes, applications, motivation, geometric-probability

I am starting a PhD, and there is a good chance that my project will be oriented in the study of random polytopes or/and random mosaics. I was wondering what are the motivations and applications of this subject. Applications inside mathematics, but also concrete application to physic, biology, computer science, statistic... are welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

Important applications include those in wireless networking, see, for example,

> Haenggi, Martin. [Stochastic Geometry for Wireless Networks](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/engineering/wireless-communications/stochastic-geometry-wireless-networks?format=HB). Cambridge University Press, November 2012.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if an outline of such applications was provided.  As it stands, this "link-only" answer would serve better as a comment to the question.